# Modular Forms on $\Gamma_0(4)$ with Nebentypus

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f$ be a modular form on $\Gamma_0(4)$ of weight $k\in\tfrac 12\mathbb{Z}$ with trivial Nebentypus.

Is it true that if you twist $f$ by $\tfrac 12$, i.e. look at the function $g$ with $g(\tau)=f(\tau+\tfrac 12)$, this is again a modular form of the same weight $k$ on $\Gamma_0(4)$, but this time with Nebentypus $\chi$, the non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo 4?

Edit: You can show that $g$ is a modular form with trivial character on $\Gamma_0(16)$:

Consider the operators $V_m$ and $U_m$. If $f(\tau)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_f(n)q^n$ is the Fourier expansion of $f$ then these operators have the following effect:
$$ (V_mf)(\tau)=\sum \alpha_f(n)q^{mn}\quad\text{and}\quad (U_mf)(\tau)=\sum\alpha_f(mn)q^n.$$
They both send modular forms on $\Gamma_0(N)$ to modular forms on $\Gamma_0(mN)$ of the same weight. (cf. http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/IntroductionToModularForms/fulltext.pdf, page 251 in the book, 14 in the pdf). If you apply $U_2$ and $V_2$ to $f$ you get the form $f_{ev}(\tau)=\sum\alpha_f(2n)q^{2n}$ on $\Gamma_0(16)$ and claearly we have $g(\tau)=2f_{ev}(\tau)-f(\tau)$.

I suppose there should either be a reference for this, which I have not been able to find, or a simple proof that I don't see right now.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I actually alreasy struggle to see that it is a modular form of $\Gamma_0(16)$. Could you at least include that computation?

Comment: I see. Thanks. On which page can I find these operators? Please always include precise reference on this forum, i.e., pages.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added them. Maybe this is not that perfect reference because there are no proofs there, but one can figure most of this out more or less easily.

Comment: So you mean $\Gamma_0(8)$. Quote from that text (next sentence): *If $m$ divides the $N$, then the mapping goes from $\Gamma_0(N)$ to $\Gamma_0(N)$*, so you get something without twist. Haven't you missed that passage or simply messed up with your notation?

Comment: Dear MHMertens, Note that $\GL_2(\mathbb Q)^+$ ($2 \times 2$ matrices with positive determinant) acts on the space of modular forms of some fixed weight $k$ via the usual "slash" action.   If $f$ is of level $\Gamma$, then $\gamma f$ (for $\gamma$ in $\GL_2(\mathbb Q)$ is 
$\gamma \Gamma \gamma^{-1}$ (since being of level $\Gamma$ is the same as being invariant by $\Gamma$ under the weight $k$ slash action). So in a question like yours, there is always *some* level
for $f|_k \gamma$,
and to figure out what it is, is just a matter of computing the conjugate $\gamma \Gamma \gamma^{-1}$. Regards,

Comment: Note: in the above, it should be $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Q)^+$ both times.

Comment: Further note: In the preceding comments $k$ is an integer; the group theoretic view-point on the half-integral case is trickier, since the metaplectic group is lurking in the background.  

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** : In what follows the weight $k$ is assumed to be an integer.

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ normalizes the group $\Gamma_0(4)$, so in your case $g$ is still a modular form on $\Gamma_0(4)$ with trivial Nebentypus.

More generally if you start with $f$ on $\Gamma_0(N)$ and twist it by $1/m$ then you get a form on $\Gamma_0(N') \cap \Gamma_1(m)$ with $N'=\operatorname{lcm}(N,m^2)$.

In general, when you consider $g(z)=f(z+1/m)$, you are twisting $f$ by the *additive* character $\alpha(n)=\exp(2\pi i n/m)$. You can always write $\alpha$ as a linear combination of (not necessarily primitive) Dirichlet characters $\chi$ of level dividing $m$. Thus you can write $g$ as a linear combination of twists $f \otimes \chi$ for such $\chi$ (up to bad Euler factors). If you want to do this completely explicitly then the formulas are quite complicated in general, see Merel, [Symboles de Manin et valeurs de fonctions L](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~merel/M70.pdf), Section 2.5. At some point, it may be useful to switch to the adelic language and work with the automorphic representation associated to the newform $f$.

Comment: Note that $f \otimes \chi$ has Nebentypus $\chi^2$ so this indicated that in general, one cannot expect $g$ to have some Nebentypus. Somehow the case $N=4$, $m=2$ is quite particular.

Comment: OK, I should have been able to figure that out by myself.

But there is still one little point of confusion: According to the dimension formula in H. Cohen's "Sums Involving the Values at Negative Integers of L-Functions of Quadratic Characters"
(http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01436180#page-1), we have dimension 1 for weight 1/2 and trivial character. The space is spanned by the ordinary theta series $\theta(\tau)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}$. But your answer would imply that also the "twisted" theta series, which is obviously not a multiple of $\theta$, belongs to this space.

Comment: What I wrote is correct if the weight is an integer, I'm not sure about the case of half-integral weight.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I realized today that I don't need this fact for half-integral weight, integral weight is enough, thus: problem solved! Thanks to all who replied.

Second: In the case of half-integral weight, I now have hints, that in that case it doesn't work at all:

The group acting in this case is not $\Gamma_0(4)$ but the Fuchsian group often denoted by $\Delta_0(4)$ (see e.g. Shimura's paper "On modular forms of half integral weight" (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970831, p. 447). This group consists of pairs of elements of $\Gamma_0(4)$ and the automorphic factor of the ordinary theta-series. Unfortunately, this group does not have a normalizing element of the form $(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \tfrac 12 \newline 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\varphi(\tau))$ for any possible automorphic factor $\varphi$ (this can be calculated directly from the group law of the Fuchsian group), thus I would now assume that my question has to be answered negatively in case of half-integral weight.

Best regards,
MHMertens